# Convert array to python scalar

Tags: python

I need big help, please check out this code:

```
import.math

dose =20.0
a = [[[2,3,4],[5,8,9],[12,56,32]]
     [[25,36,45][21,65,987][21,58,89]]
     [[78,21,98],[54,36,78],[23,12,36]]]
PAC = math.exp(-dose*a)
```

this what I would like to do. However the error I am getting is

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: My expected out put is in the same shape of a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to perform mathematical operations on arrays (whatever their dimensions...), you should really consider using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) which is designed just for that. In your case, the corresponding NumPy command would be:

```
PAC = numpy.exp(-dose*np.array(a))
```

If NumPy is not an option, you'll have to loop on each element of `a`, compute your `math.exp`, store the result in a list... Really cumbersome and inefficient. That's because the `math` functions require a scalar as input (as the exception told you), when you're passing a list (of lists). You can combine all the loops in a single list comprehension, though:

```
PAC = [[[math.exp(-dose*j) for j in elem] for elem in row] for row in a]
```

but once again, I would strongly recommend NumPy.

Answer (score 2):

You should really use NumPy for that.
And here is how you should do it using nested loops:

```
>>> for item in a:
...     for sub in item:
...         for idx, number in enumerate(sub): 
...             print number, math.exp(-dose*number)
...             sub[idx] = math.exp(-dose*number)
```

Using `append` is slow, because every time you copy the previous array and stack the new item to it. 
Using enumerate, changes numbers in place. If you want to keep a copy of a, do:

```
 acopy = a[:]
```

If you don't have much numbers, and NumPy is an over kill, the above could be done a tiny bit faster using list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, for each element of the array to have it multiplied by -dose then apply math.exp on the result, you need a loop :

```
new_a = []
for subarray in a:
    new_sub_array = []
    for element in sub_array:
        new_element = math.exp(-dose*element)
        new_sub_array.append(new_element)
    new_a.append(new_sub_array)
```

Alternatvely, if you have a mathlab background, you could inquire [numpy](http://numpy.org), that enable transformations on array.

Comment: I have done it this way mainly for readability. the OP seems quite a (python) beginner. Besides, while changing in place is easy, you lose the original array which is often not desirable in processing coding.

Comment: I also posted how you can keep a copy of the list. Using append when iterating of lists is a bad style IMHO. Plus, it is all over the net, and then after one of programming, you ask yourself: wait how do i iterate and change values. There for we have enumrate. That is what OP asked, how to change the values.

Comment: Lets agree to disagree, then. My goal was readability first and keeping the original list second. Using enumerate don't fit with that. The OP is clearly a beginner, style matters when you understand the language.