# Converting arrays to scalars with numpy and scipy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import math
import pylab

y0=np.array([1,3,2,3,5])
b=np.array([[1],[3],[4],[2],[5]])

'''make a matrix'''
B=np.dot(b,b.T)
def g(t,y,B):
    return math.exp(np.dot(y,B))
t=np.linspace(0,1,100)
y= odeint(g, y0, t, args=(B,))
```

I tried to solve the dynamic system of `y` with following code.
As it runs, the error `only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars` comes out. I am still confused about how to convert it to `size-1` array. Could you give me some suggestions for how to fix the error.

Comment: You might find these similar threads helpful: [A solid discussion on manipulating arrays in Python/numpy.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680402/typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-while-plot-sh) [You already are using numpy (yay!), but this thread includes explicit examples of how to navigate numpy arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296021/convert-array-to-python-scalar)

Comment: Take another look at the [odeint docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html); it expects the first argument of `func` to be `y`, not `t`.  Your definition should be `def g(y, t, B):`.  (I'd make this an answer, but the question is surely a dup--in fact, I'm pretty sure I've pointed out this problem more than once before.)

Comment: By the way, are you sure you have the correct mathematical formulation of your differential equations?  What you show will exhibit explosive growth.  The numerical values will overflow standard floating point representation *very* quickly.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by the others, you have to use `np.exp`, instead of `math.exp` to solve your error. The other issue is due to the fact that `g` has the wrong order in the call: you must pass the `y`s first, then time (even if it is not used in the function), then the extra arguments. Have a look at [the help page and example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).
Something like the following works, in the sense that no exceptions are raised, but the system rapidly diverges. If you can describe what you are actually trying to do from a mathematical point of view, there may be further insights.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import pylab

y0=np.array([1,3,2,3,5])
b=np.array([[1],[3],[4],[2],[5]])

# make a matrix
B=np.dot(b,b.T)
def g(y, t, B):
    return np.exp(np.dot(y,B))
t=np.linspace(0,1,100)
y= odeint(g, y0, t, args=(B,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
def g(t,y,B):
    return math.exp(np.dot(y,B))
```

to:

```
def g(t,y,B):
    return np.exp(np.dot(y,B))
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. But the error "The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2." comes out as I change it to np.exp. Do you know what does this error represents? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error is being caused by `math.exp()`
Try using `np.exp()` instead

But this doesn't completely resolve the issue yet, it still results in this error:

```
RuntimeError: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=2.
```